# Anaconda cannot find win-64 endpoint

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm trying to get Anaconda to install packages after installation on my Windows 10 computer, but it's not working. It's erroring out with this:

```
Fetching package metadata: 
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Error: Could not find URL: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win-64/
```

Here is my `.condarc` file:

```
channels:
  - https://pypi.python.org/pypi
  - defaults
```

I checked on PyPi, and it definitely doesn't exist, but I'm not sure how to resolve it since this is my first time using Anaconda. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So...after Googling, I found a random [forum about linux-64](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/a4sK6kZdleo) issues, and that solved my problem on Windows because apparently Anaconda can't use PyPi for x,y,z reasons. I removed the PyPi link from my `.condarc` and that fixed it.